# How do I send a javax.jms.TextMessage over Azure Servicebus from .NET

Tags: java, azure, amqp, servicebus

I am trying to send a simple string message from .NET to a Java client using amqp over the azure service bus.  According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj841073.aspx) I should be able to send a brokered message like this:

```
message = new BrokeredMessage("this is a text string");
```

and have it show up in the Java client as a TextMessage (javax.jms.TextMessage). However when I try and cast the message in Java as a TextMessage I get an exception saying it cant convert a jms.impl.BytesMessageImpl to a TextMessage.  Anyone know why the message looks like a BytesMessage rather than a TextMessage?

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj841073.aspx) a BytesMessage would be built like this:

```
byte[] bytes = { 33, 12, 45, 33, 12, 45, 33, 12, 45, 33, 12, 45 };
message = new BrokeredMessage(bytes);
```

which I am not doing....

Anyone know how to do something like this?

**[Update]**
Interestingly, I tested my sending code with and without the TransportType=Amqp designation in my connection string. I also verified the code while it was running that the MessagingFactory settings were also set to the correct Transport Type each time. No matter which Transport type I used the message arrives to my Java app as a BytesMessage. Looking at the bytes in the message reveals the same result no matter how the message is sent:

```
@ string 3http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/�&BLABLA this is a message
```

**[UPDATE2]**
I figured out the root cause of my issue. In my setup I have a subscriber that is forwarding messages to a queue. It appears that this is where the messages are getting messed up. If I send an AMQP message directly to the queue it comes to my Java app as a TextMessage. If I send the message to my Topic via AMQP and it then gets forwarded to my queue via a subscriber (with a filter) it gets mangled into a BytesMessage.

So how do I get this to work properly? Is there a way to setup my subscriber that is forwarding to the queue so this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s currently a limitation to the Service Bus AMQP interoperability story when using forwarding rules. During the forwarding, the message is incorrectly being re-serialized using data contract serializer. We’ll address that problem and I’ll report back here when that’s been done. In the meantime, a possible workaround would be to use message properties to store the application data rather than the body. That is, use a string property on the message to store the salient information rather than using the body.

Best regards,

Dave.

Service Bus team

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written looks correct. The only thing I can think of is that you have an old version of the .NET SDK, one that was issued before AMQP support was added. Can you try your code with the latest Service Bus SDK from http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/.

Regards,

Dave.

(Service Bus Team.)

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the input. I am using the latest version of the ServiceBus SDK so that's not the issue. I added some additional info to my original question about why I think this is happening.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Let me check that out and get back to you.

Comment: I would appreciate that a lot David, its a big deal for us to be able to replicate messages to private queues for our customers. - thanks